# Generic list of generic objects

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

Let's say I have an object that represents a field of data, that object needs the following properties: Name, Type, Value, Length. Here is the object:

```
class Field<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have used generics, because I want to force the user of the code to only be able to assign a Value of certain Type.
Now the problem is when I want to create a list of fields.
If I create the list like `List<Field<object>>` then we can assign any Value to a given Field on the list, and when we query for Type, we get 'object'.
The thing is - on that list I might want few fields holding strings, few holding ints, dates, and even custom objects that in turn will have a list of Fields...
Is the Generics a good solution for something like that? If yes, how would I go about implementing it? If not, what is a better way?

---EDIT---
Just to add some more background:
1. I might want a list of fields, and each field will hold different data type, like so :

```
List<Field<object>> lst = new List<Field<object>>();
lst.Add(new Field<string>());
lst.Add(new Field<int>());
lst.Add(new Field<SomeObjectFromMyApp>());
```

2. Later on I will have to query these objects, and their attributes automaticaly in a loop, something like that:

```
foreach(Field<object> fld in lst)
{
    Type t = fld.Type;
    //do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly ? I don't understand this sentence : "on that list I might want few fields holding strings, few holding ints, dates, and even custom objects that in turn will have a list of Fields"

Comment: Exactly what it says, I will have few different lists of Fields, but each Field on that list might be holding different data type (int, string or some custom object).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, generics is a good choice. The key to achieving type-safety (and being identify the type with the `Type` property is to add an abstraction between the list and `Field<T>` class.

Have `Field<T>` implement the interface `IField`. This interface doesn't need any members.

Then declare your list as being `List<IField>`.

That way you constrain the list to only contain fields, but each field can be of a different type.

To then read the values later, just do

```
foreach(var field in list)
{
    var type = field.Type;
    ....
}
```

Comment: That would solve a problem with creating the list, but it wouldn't solve the problem of reading values back, since now I would have to cast to an appropriate Field<_type_> , and there is no way I know the \_type\_ at that time...

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk Why would you need to cast? Either of these will work fine: var field = list[index] or IField field = list[index]

Comment: I will check it out, as the interface would actually suit me much better since I can enforce certain methods on the class :)

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk consider you have two fields in your `Field<int>` and `Field<string>` you either need casting to process fields or runtime dynamic type resolving.

Comment: thanks for a good idea. I ended up discovering that I need an extended functionality and therefore went with an abstract class and a factory pattern to create all different types of fields. I am marking your answer as correct since attempt at implementing an interface like you suggested led me to my final, working solution. Thanks.

Comment: You get a list of IField's, which contain no data.

Comment: @Wish, they contain data; that data just isn't accessible without casting. Looking at this answer three years later though, I do not understand why it was upvoted. The `var type = field.Type;` line is nonsense and wouldn't compile.

Comment: @DavidArno 2 years later, I stumbled upon this question and I noticed that `var type = field.Type` won't compile, however, there's a simple fix for that. You could simply use `dynamic type = field.Type` and everything is good to go. So maybe adding this to the answer helps someone. Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

I suggest you to define an interface and `Field<T>` implements that interface

```
public interface IField
{

}

public class Field<T> : IField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

so you can write this code:

```
var list = new List<IField>();
```

now this list can contain any object of type `Field<T>`

Comment: What's the benefit of repeating an existing answer?

Comment: There was only 4 minutes between them. If you're a slow typer like me, you might not have noticed the other answer.

Comment: Yes I didn't notice the other answer :)

Answer (score 13):

As a few commenters already mentioned, you cannot access the `Type` property if you create an empty Interface, so I would rather do:

```
public interface IField
{
    Type Type { get; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    int Length { get; set; }
}

public class Field<T> : IField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    Type IField.Type => typeof(T);

    public int Length { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can check of which datatype the value property is and cast the object to the right type:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fieldList = new List<IField>()
        {
            new Field<string>()
            {
                Value = "Hello World!", 
                Length = 12, 
                Name = "A string"
            },
            new Field<int>()
            {
                Value = 4711,
                Length = sizeof(int),
                Name = "An integer value"
            },
            new Field<double>()
            {
                Value = 2.4,
                Length = sizeof(double),
                Name = "A double value"
            },
        };

        foreach (var field in fieldList)
        {
            if (field.Type == typeof(string))
            {
                PrintField(field, "String value:");
            }
            else if (field.Type == typeof(int))
            {
                PrintField(field, "Integer value:");
            }
            else if (field.Type == typeof(double))
            {
                PrintField(field, "Double value:");
            }
        }
    }

    static void PrintField(IField field, string info)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(info);
        Debug.WriteLine($"\tName: {field.Name}, Length: {field.Length}, Value: {field}");
    }
}
```

The code produces the following output:

```
// String value:
//  Name: A string, Length: 12, Value: Hello World!
// Integer value:
//     Name: An integer value, Length: 4, Value: 4711
// Double value:
//     Name: A double value, Length: 8, Value: 2,4
```