# C# List of generic class that implements a type-specific function

Tags: c#, generics

**Update:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490819/generic-list-of-generic-objects) is what I was trying to ask for, but couldn't figure out how.

Essentially what I need is a list of values, but I don't care what types those values are as long as they implement a few different functions. Something like this:

```
List<MagicType> values1 = new List<MagicType>();
List<MagicType> values2 = someAlreadyExistingListOfMagicType;

Vector3 position = someVector3;
Quaternion rotation = someQuat;
bool sleeping = false;

values1.Add(new MagicType<Vector3>(position));
values1.Add(new MagicType<Quaternion>(rotation));
values1.Add(new MagicType<bool>(sleeping));

List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

foreach(MagicType value1 in values1)
{
    foreach(MagicType value2 in values2)
    {
        if(value1.Compare(Value2))
        {
            result.AddRange(value1.GetBytes());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if what I want is normal or not. I've tried doing this:

```
public class MagicClass<T>
{
    private T value;
    
    public MagicClass(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public bool Compare(T a, T b)
    {
        return a == b;
    }
    
    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        //somehow return byte array
    }
}
```

But that complains that operator '==' can't be applied to types T and T.

I'm sure there must be a straightforward solution here but I've spent so long on this I can't think straight any more. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: _"I need a way for IMagicType to understand what the type is"_ -- _maybe_ you should make it generic? Your question is very difficult to understand. The values you show above to be added to the list, **cannot** be added to the list, because they don't implement your arbitrary interface `IMagicType`, whatever that is. _Maybe_ instead of `IMagicType`, you just want `IComparable`? Perhaps you should not have posted the question until you resolved the problem that you are _"having trouble getting my head around how to even ask this question"_. As it stands now, it's very unclear.

Comment: Did you tried to make `IMagicType` to inherit from `IComparable<IMagicType>` and some custom `IByteConvertible<IMagicType>`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I hoped it was at least clear what I wanted, even if I can't get my head around how to achieve it. I just need a list of values, but I don't care what types those values are as long as they implement a few different functions. I've edited the question so it's hopefully clearer what I'm after/have tried.

Comment: @JL0PD I'm not sure what I was thinking with naming it `IMagicType` to imply it's an interface. I'm pretty sure that's not what I want at all. I've edited the question so hopefully it makes more sense now. When you say make `IMagicType` inherit from `IComparable<IMagicType>`... is that a thing? Can a class/interface inherit from a generic class of the first class's type?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper Perhaps. I'm writing a networking layer that allows for easy-ish automatic rollback networking, but I need a sensible way to store entity data that doesn't require the end user to manually type out long switch-cases for "if valueId == 0, compare the Vector3 position variable" etc. because [this](https://pastebin.com/PgN0NgL5) kind of thing is quite gross, especially if you have to do that for dozens or hundreds of different entity types.

Comment: Can't you use `object` as your type instead of generics to solve the problem?  That would get rid of your compile error.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want to do is have `T` constrained to implement a particular interface, but you haven't defined what that interface should look like

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah I think I've actually figured out what I want, and probably how to implement it. I'll have to wait until I get home from to work properly test it though. I hate when I get stuck like this, because the only way to get unstuck is to ask an apparently-stupid or nonsensical question and hope people can figure out what my end goal is. Normally I have a pretty clear understanding of the problem I'm trying to solve but in this case it was all just a mess. I think I actually found a good dupe of my true question so I'll link to that later.

Comment: If you hate [that](https://pastebin.com/PgN0NgL5) just because it's verbose and hard to maintain across multiple entities, .Net5 provides source generators which can automatically build code for you while compiling. You get the full syntax tree and semantics analyzer support and can just inject your own code as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But that complains that operator '==' can't be applied to types T and T.

```
public class MagicClass<T>
{
    private T value;
    
    public MagicClass(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;

    
    public bool Compare(T a, T b)  // what is this?
    {
        return a == b;
    }
    
    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        //somehow return byte array
    }
}
```

Nowhere in that function did you define what `operator==` is supposed to be.

In fact, not only did you not define the required operator, you tried to use it in a random function called `Compare` which by convention does **not** return a `bool`, it returns a compare result. The function provided by the framework to test equality is called, perhaps strangely enough, `Equals`.

So, a little bit of correct code will patch your class right up!

```
public class MagicClass<T>: IEquatable<MagicClass<T>>
{
    private T value;

    public MagicClass(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object objB) => 
        objB is MagicClass<T> b ? value == b.value : false;

    public bool Equals(MagicClass<T> b) => value == b.Value;

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        //somehow return byte array
    }
}
```

I threw in a standard `IEquatable<>` interface implementation for you. Keep in mind that the other piece of code you're missing is overriding the `GetHashCode()` function. If you set up your project correctly, you'll get a long warning about it.

Comment: I'm very confused, but this has made clear another issue with my intentions. My intention was to have the `Compare` function intelligently compare different types. So Vector3s might need to be more than 0.01f different in magnitude to count as different, but that means I need to have implementations of MagicClass for each type. Or something. Right, well I clearly have no idea what I'm talking about. I'll be back when I've cleared things up in my head. Also, it's worth mentioning that your code doesn't fix [one of the issues](https://i.imgur.com/TrdP2EX.png). And why do I have to define `==`?

Comment: @Clonkex That is one and the same issue. You haven't defined `==` operator, so how does the compiler know what to do when we write `value == b.value` You need another way of defining equality over `T`. Perhaps `T` itself needs to be constrained `where T : IEquatable<T>` the you can instead call `value?.Equals(b.value)`

Comment: @Charlieface I don't understand why I need to define `==` (or even how to, for that matter) What's the difference between this and every other class I've ever created? I've never needed to define `==` before in my life. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I really don't understand why it doesn't know what T will be. If it knows what T will be (which surely it has to, because that's the whole point of generics) then surely it can happily compare the values because it knows their type.

Comment: @Clonkex Firstly, normally one can define an operator like this `public static operator ==(...` In this case you obviously cannot, as you do not have `T` to define it on. Compiler does not **know** if `T` already has `==` defined on it, it may be a struct which doesn't have `==` defined. If you constrain `T` to be a class `where T: class` then yes it **does** know. The "whole point of generics" is to tell the compiler that `T` can be replaced by the actual type. But if we need for example `T` to have certain properties, we must constrain it to only allow a type that fulfills that

Comment: Ahhhhh ok, now we're getting somewhere. I hadn't considered that a struct might not automatically be able to test for equality. I hardly ever use structs so that's not something I've come across before (there's a first time for everything). I guess because it's a value type it's not as simple as comparing a reference. Now I also understand why you suggest `where T : IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: Reference types (classes) also have no pre-defined equality operator, they inherit the base `object.Equals` which just calls `object.ReferenceEquals`. If you want support for equality, you have to define in which way your objects are equal.