# Combining Generics of Interface in List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I am sorry if this question is not phrased correctly as I am quite new to generic programming. Therefore some terms may not be used correctly but I hope you get a grasp of my problem.

### What would I like to achieve

I want a base class or better an base interface which has multiple generic types. From this base I would like to create multiple classes. These derived classes must not have a declaration of the types at initizializing as I would like to use them as an alias.

Example:

- **Base interface**

```cs
public interface IWidgetHandler<T1, T2, T3>
{
    protected T1 Config { get; set; }

    protected T1 ParseConfig();
    public T2 GetConfigResponse();
    public T3 ProcessRequest(T2 r);
    
}
```

- **Derived class**

```cs
public class SomeWidget : IWidgetHandler<bool, bool, bool>
{
    protected bool Config { get; set; }

    protected bool ParseConfig();
    public bool GetConfigResponse();
    public bool ProcessRequest(bool r);
}

public class SomeOtherWidget : IWidgetHandler<bool, byte, bool>
{
    protected bool Config { get; set; }

    protected bool ParseConfig();
    public byte GetConfigResponse();
    public bool ProcessRequest(byte r);
}
```

Until now it works fine but I would also like to be able to combine them into a list and also something like `List<IWidgetHandler<dynamic,dynamic,dynamic>>` does not work. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "These derived classes must not have a declaration of the types at initizializing as I would like to use them as an alias." - what do you mean by this?

Comment: What do you mean by "has multiple generic types" in "I want a base class or better an base interface which has multiple generic types."? Do you mean "has member-properties typed as the type-arguments"? If so, your code shows that, so what's the problem?

Comment: "I would also like to be able to combine them into a list" - you can't, at least not without introducing a new non-generic common interface if you want any semblance of type-safety.

Comment: I don’t want to always type the same long sequence over and over again. 
But I am more concerned on how to combine these classes in an List.

Comment: You'd need a wrapper class like `AnyWidgetHandler`, which implements `IWidgetHandler<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>`, and then possibly add an implicit conversion to that class, or just a constructor. I also question the use of `dynamic` here... Everything about this is not type safe at all. Do you realise that?

Comment: C# has type-aliases for this purpose, just do `using MyType = WidgetHandler<bool, byte, bool>;`.

Comment: The `dynamic` type in C# should be avoided wherever possible. I feel Microsoft made a mistake by adding it to the language. It's hardly better than `Object` (it still boxes value-types, for example).

Comment: I would be happy to introduce another Interfaxe. But does this have the same methods? I don’t think so. I guess this architecture itself is flawed. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Some of the discussion here might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490819/generic-list-of-generic-objects

Comment: Ok. Let me extend the use case a little bit. I want to bundle the parsing of a part of the configuration file, the requesting of a config over an HTTP API, the handling of some requests (each widget is different) and the component that should be rendered in one project.

Comment: Mastering generics is about knowing when to **not** use them.

Comment: @Alex1234 "the requesting of a config over an HTTP API" - you can't use open generics as DTOs in _most_ web platforms because it requires serialization to include type-information which inevitably leads to huge problems later on (as it is the opposite of _loose coupling_). Some platforms don't even support closed-generics: Swagger, for example, doesn't support the concept of closed nor open generic DTOs at all. Anyway, it's _always_ a mistake to reuse an in-proc business/domain/entity class as a DTO so _just don't do it_.